# Infimum of a function of two variables.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, inequality, examples-counterexamples

The following result holds true:

> For a real function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\inf_{x,y} F(x,y)\leq \inf_x (\inf_y F(x,y)) $.

My question is on whether or not it is possible to provide an example where we have strict inequality? If so, I would be interested in seeing an example. If not, why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is never strict inequality

Comment: is it in general true that when you have a function of N-variables you can find the infimum in an iterated way?

Comment: no, because $\inf_x (\inf_y F(x,y)) $ is not iterated; it is $\inf_x g(x)$ with $g(x) = \inf_y F(x,y)$, and finding $g(x)$ is hard

Answer (score 1):

In fact, given any two non-empty sets $X,\,Y$ and $f:X\times Y\to\mathbb{R},$ we have equality since:
$$
\forall (x,y)\in X\times Y:\,f(x,y)\geq\inf_{y}f(x,y)\geq\inf_{x}\left(\inf_{y}f(x,y)\right)
\\
\implies \inf_{x,y} f(x,y)\geq\inf_{x}\left(\inf_{y}f(x,y)\right)
$$
While inequality in the other direction holds since:
$$
\forall x\in X:\,\inf_{y}f(x,y)\geq \inf_{x,y}f(x,y)\implies \inf_{x}\left(\inf_{y}f(x,y)\right)\geq \inf_{x,y}f(x,y).
$$
This argument can be easily generalised to take the infimum of a real-valued function with $N$ arguments.